# Docker - Is it possible to recreate volume container without recreating the containers that use it

Tags: docker, containers, volume

I have created a volume container then created a container that used it, ex:

- volume container: `argus-data`
- app container: `argus-app` (used `--volumes-from argus-data`)

Then I realized I made a typo on the mounted volumes inside the `argus-data` container.

Can I just recreate `argus-data` without recreating all of its dependent containers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `--volumes-from` argument is really just a one-time deal. It tells your newly created container to grab any volumes referenced in the existing container you are referring to. Once that new container is created with those volumes, there is no persisting reference to existing container.

Containers volumes can't be changed once the container is created. You'll need to create new containers that refer to the volumes without the typo.

Comment: Yes, I just gave it up and re-created the whole stack. I just created a bash script instead to automate the creation of volume container and creation of the app container. Thanks!